# errror with Describe Function on DATAFRAME

Tags: python, pandas

Im trying to use the Describe function on a DataFrame to do some statistical analysis - see error message below - Any help would be greatly appreciated

> > > import pandas as pd
> > >       from pandas import DataFrame as df
> > >       y=[{'playerID':'bushje01','year':'1945','stint':'0','tmID':'FTW','lgID':'NBL','GP':'34','GS':'0','minutes':'0','points':'153','oRebounds':'0','dRebounds':'0','rebounds':'0','assists':'0','steals':'0','blocks':'0','turnovers':'0','PF':'92','fgAttempted':'0','fgMade':'61','ftAttempted':'43','PostfgAttempted':'0','PostfgMade':'3','PostftAttempted':'12','PostftMade':'7','PostthreeMade':'0'},
> > >       {'playerID':'doerngu01','year':'1945','stint':'0','tmID':'FTW','lgID':'NBL','GP':'11','GS':'0','minutes':'0','points':'21','oRebounds':'0','dRebounds':'0','rebounds':'0','assists':'0','steals':'0','blocks':'0','turnovers':'0','PF':'0','fgAttempted':'0','fgMade':'8','ftAttempted':'0','PostfgAttempted':'0','PostfgMade':'0','PostftAttempted':'0','PostftMade':'0','PostthreeMade':'0'}]
> > >
> > > pd.DataFrame(y)
> > >          GP GS  PF PostfgAttempted PostfgMade PostftAttempted PostftMade  \
> > >       0  34  0  92               0          3              12          7
> > >       1  11  0   0               0          0               0          0

PostthreeMade assists blocks  ...  minutes oRebounds   playerID points  \
0             0       0      0  ...        0         0   bushje01    153
1             0       0      0  ...        0         0  doerngu01     21

rebounds steals stint tmID turnovers  year
0        0      0     0  FTW         0  1945
1        0      0     0  FTW         0  1945

> > > df.Describe(y)
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >           df.Describe(y)
> > >       AttributeError: type object 'DataFrame' has no attribute 'Describe'

Just wondering if anyone knows what this error

Answer (score 0):

You probably wanted to use:

```
df.describe()
```

Note lower case ['.describe'](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html)

Comment: Thanks for this, that seems to have solved some of the problem, but now I'm getting a new error! Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 1, in df.describe(X) File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 3748, in describe if self.ndim >= 3: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'ndim'

Any ideas how to solve it?!

Comment: You're trying to call `ndim` on a list object, but you need to call it from a `numpy.ndarray` object.

Comment: Thanks for this,I'm really new to python,could you explain what this means and suggest a code? I have numpy installed:-)